# Error in creating secret in AKS cluster using kubectl

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

I am creating a secret in AKS cluster using --

```
kubectl -n dynatrace create secret generic oneagent 
—-from-literal=“apiToken=[value_here]” —from-literal=“passToken= [value_here]”
```

Version of kubectl -

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.3",
GitCommit:"1e11e4a2108024935ecfcb2912226cedeafd99df",
GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-14T12:50:19Z",
GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

But I am getting error as below -

```
error: exactly one NAME is required, got 3
See 'kubectl create secret generic -h' for help and examples
```

Comment: how about you use: `kubectl create secret generic oneagent -n dynatrace xxx`

Comment: Tried it .. did not work..

Comment: Try `kubectl -n dynatrace create secret generic oneagent --from-literal="apiToken=[value_here]" --from-literal="passToken=[value_here]"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `—-from-literal=“apiToken=[value_here]”` isn't processed correctly, it sees a space in `“apiToken=[value_here]”` and therefore thinks you're providing a new name.

Possible solutions:

- It seems that you are using ” (Unicode RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) instead of " (ASCII 0x22). Instead of `“` quotes, use `"`  (macos/linux) or `'` (windows).
- Your second `from-literal` has is preceded by only one dash (`-`) instead of two (`--`)
- No space here: `= [value_here]` but `=[value_here]`
- If this doesn't work, first try if you can create the secret without `-n dynatrace`

Comment: Thanks Casper. Except for your first point I had corrected/tried everything else. I tried using quotes from your answer, still the same error.

Comment: I read that, if you're using windows, you should use `'`rather than `"`

Comment: For the moment i created a secret file and used kubectl apply -f filename.yaml as a workaround